# angular 2/4 save ContentChild template as string

Tags: angular

I have component `app-preview` which has a pushed component by it's  parent into it's `ng-content`.

The code of `app-preview`s' parent :

```
<app-preview>
      <checkbox #prv
        [indeterminate]="true"
        [checked]="true">
      </checkbox>
</app-preview>
```

I want `app-preview` not just to render, but also to save as a string into any property the template of any component which was pushed to it's `ng-content`. So I want `app-preview` to save the following string:

```
  "<checkbox #prv
    [indeterminate]="true"
    [checked]="true">
  </checkbox>"
```

into it's property and use it in it's `.ts` file. 
For example : `this.childTmpl`

How can I achieve that?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you are using `@angular/compiler`.

So in this case it can be easily done by overriding for example `I18NHtmlParser.parse` method:

```
import { Attribute as HtmlAttribute, I18NHtmlParser } from '@angular/compiler';

function visitAll(visitor: any, nodes: any[]): any[] {
  const result: any[] = [];
  nodes.forEach(ast => ast.visit(visitor));
  return result;
}

class MyVisitor {
  visitElement(ast: any) {
    if(ast.name === 'app-preview') {
      const text = ast.sourceSpan.start.file.content
             .substring(ast.startSourceSpan.end.offset, ast.endSourceSpan.start.offset);
      ast.attrs.push(new HtmlAttribute('childTmpl', text, ast.startSourceSpan))
    }
    visitAll(this, ast.children);
  }
  visitAttribute() {}
  visitText() {}
  visitComment() {}
}
const originParse = I18NHtmlParser.prototype.parse;
const visitor = new MyVisitor();
I18NHtmlParser.prototype.parse = function() {
  const result = originParse.apply(this, arguments);
  visitAll(visitor, result.rootNodes)
  return result;
};
```

It will collect text between `app-preview` tag and pass it to `childTmpl` attribute that will be converted to `@Input`.

After that you can get ContentChild string in

**app-preview.component.ts**

```
export class AppPreview {
   @Input() childTmpl: string;

   ngOnInit() {
     console.log(this.childTmpl);
   }
}
```

If you want to see it in action then look at the **[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/gLgV0dRYXYp8H4zZPHae?p=preview)**

*P.S.* **Do not do it if you do not know what it does.**

To see how angular parses template look at

https://alexzuza.github.io/enjoy-ng-parser

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Do I get it right that this will override I18NHtmlParser.parse in the whole project? If yes - unfortunately I'm not allowed to do override plugins or angular classes globally in the project :(

Comment: Yeah, you're right. But you can write `I18NHtmlParser.prototype.parse = originParse` to restore the original behavior

Answer (score 0):

Try to add a reference to your app-preview

```
<app-preview [title]="'PREVIEW'" [id]="'prev'" #test>
      <checkbox #prv
        [indeterminate]="true"
        [checked]="true">
      </checkbox>
</app-preview>
```

And in your .ts file you can receive the inner HTML of your native element and save it as you like:

```
@ViewChild('test') input:ElementRef; 

ngAfterViewInit() {
  console.log(this.input.nativeElement.innerHTML);
}
```

Don't forget to import ElementRef and ViewChild.

Comment: 1) app-preview is the component which should get the ng-content template. It can not ViewChild itself 2) innerHTML is compiled template. And I need exactly a template